# Which container and locking mechanism to use?

Tags: c++, multithreading, hashmap

I have 2 threads, first - player tick, second - rendering.
Both threads not synced.
I need to collect information in first thread and render it in second.
In tick thread I collecting information using 2 loops.
Everytime it enter code in tick thread all the list of render targets should be reset.
I collecting these targets from 2 loops, the list must be associative, but very fast because of rendering.

```
void TickThread()
{
   g_pLock->Enter(); //EnterCriticalSection
   g_List.clear(); //clear list of targets
   for (obj1 : g_Objects1) //first loop of objects
   {
     if (obj1 && true) // here's selection
        g_List[obj1->uid] = obj1; //create
   }
   for (obj2 : g_Objects2) //another loop of objects
   {
     if (obj2 && true) // here's selection
        g_List[obj2->uid] = obj2; //replace if already exists or create
   }
   g_pLock->Leave(); //code must be fast enough, otherwise it will lock rendering
}

void RenderThread()
{
   g_pLock->Enter(); //EnterCriticalSection
   for (obj : g_List) //iterate over whole list
   {
      //render obj.first obj.second
   }
   g_pLock->Leave();
}
```

Maybe I need some hashmap, also maximal count of objects is 64
Which container should I use, it should be very fast, also keep in mind that I know maximal count of targets, so can allocate memory at start?
Also what to use for locking?
I'm not sure that std::map good idea...
Thank you

Comment: why are those two threads and why are they not synched when in fact there is a sequential dependency between them?

Comment: It's not mine, I just hooking them both

Comment: Um... what is your question?

Comment: Which container should I use, it should be very fast, also keep in mind that I know maximal count of targets, so can allocate memory at start?

Comment: [Edit] your question so that the question is clear

Answer (score 1):

you can use std::map as they are fast. The size is flexible you can use it to be extended in future. Also as described in the problem the threads should be synced.